# processing arguments with bash function

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a bash script which is initiated with arguments, I have a function to process arguments. I place the arguments in an array `args=("$@")`. and I have a function which can check if the argument does contain certain elements.

```
containsElement () {
  local e
  for e in "${@:2}"; do [[ "$e" == "$1" ]] && { ipos="$i"; return 0; }
  done
  return 1
}
```

I wanted to improve my function with the ability that; After finding the argument, check the **next** arguments and see if they contain numbers **until the next non numerical element in array is found**, put them in an array of opt[1], opt[2], ...
It's better explained in an example;

```
sh script.sh plt 2 3 g40 All 32
```

then I want the function give me

```
if containsElement "plt" "${args[@]}" ; then
containsElement "plt" "${args[@]}"
echo ${opt[@]}
fi
```

give me

```
2 3 g40
```

The number are options for each argument.
I can write something to do this but it turns to an ugly code, I wanted to learn a nice way to do it.

Comment: I would rethink the whole thing. You should have a she-bang at the top, #! /bin/bash perhaps and thus do not need to call it with sh . bash may be a better choice - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash

Comment: Also read this: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I'll do it with regexes, for example:

```
echo plt 2 3 g40 All 32|perl -ne's/(\w+) ([\d ]+)(\w+)/print "$1$2$3\n"/egx;'

plt 2 3 g40
All 32
```

Not sure if it's what you are looking for? You can omit printing the first string for each parameter group, with:

```
echo plt 2 3 g40 All 32|perl -ne's/(\w+) ([\d ]+)(\w+)/print "$2$3\n"/egx;'
```